# Drawing GRTS points within polygons with spsurvey

Tags: r, polygon, draw

In previous versions of the spsurvey package, it was possible to draw random points within polygons in a shapefile using a somewhat complicated `design` specification. (See [here](https://schmidtynotes.com/r/sample%20design/2019/11/19/spsurvey_grts.html) for an example).

The newly updated version of `spsurvey` (5.0.1) appears very user-friendly, except I cannot figure out how to perform a GRTS draw of more than one point within polygons. Below is an example:

Suppose I want to draw 10 random points using GRTS within the states of Montana and Wyoming. The `grts()` call requires an sf object, so we can get an sf object first.

```
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(spsurvey)

## Get state outlines
US <- raster::getData(country = "United States", level = 1)
States.outline <- US[US$NAME_1 %in% c("Montana","Wyoming"),]

# convert to sf object
states.out <- st_as_sf(States.outline)
```

Then, if we want to stratify by state, and we want ten points from each, we need:

```
# Define the number of points to draw from each state
strata_n <- c(Montana = 10, Wyoming = 10)
```

The `strata_n` object then gets fed into the `grts()` call, with the `NAME_1` variable being the state name.

```
# Attempt to make grts draw 
grts(sframe = states.out, 
     stratum_var = "NAME_1", 
     n_base = strata_n
     )
```

This returns an error message:

> During the check of the input to grtspts, one or more errors were
> identified. Enter the following command to view all input error
> messages: stopprnt() To view a subset of the errors (e.g., errors 1
> and 5) enter stopprnt(m=c(1,5))

Running `stopprnt()` gives the following message:

> Input       Error Message n_base :  Each stratum must have a sample
> size no larger than the number of rows in 'sframe' representing that
> stratum

This is a wonderfully clear message -- we can't draw more than one point from each polygon because the sf object only has a single row per state.

So: with the new and improved `spsurvey` package, how does one draw multiple points from within a polygon? Any tips or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. I have updated the development version, which can be installed (after installing the remotes package) by running

```r
remotes::install_github("USEPA/spsurvey", ref = "develop")
```

Likely a few weeks before the changes in spsurvey are reflected on CRAN. Thanks for finding this.

Comment: Thanks @Michael -- I downloaded the develop version and it looks like there may still be an error (at least when drawing a grts sample in the example question above): `Error in st_poly_sample(x, size = size, ..., type = type, by_polygon = by_polygon) : hexagonal sampling on geographic coordinates not supported; consider projecting first`.

Comment: @Jacob_Oram The error occurs because you are using geographic coordinates, not projected coordinates; for more information, see section 6 and 7 in spsurvey's "Start Here" vignette [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spsurvey/vignettes/start-here.html) and the references therein. If your data are in North America, NAD 83 / Conus Albers (crs = 5070) is usually fine.

Comment: @Jacob_Oram I will add a more informative error message in the next spsurvey update. Thanks again.

Comment: That worked just fine using `sf::st_transform()` as suggested. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: @Jacob_Oram These changes are now reflected on CRAN in version 5.1.0

Comment: Excellent. Thanks again for the prompt fix Michael!